# Why the first code displays error message immediately, but second not

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, task-parallel-library

Lets say we have two button clicks:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        using (
            System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => {
                throw new Exception("puzzle");

            }))
        {
            t.Start();
        }
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() => {
                                  throw new Exception("puzzle");

        });
        t.Start();
}
```

If to run program with those two event handlers for buttons without debugging, then button2_Click causes error message appears immediately. But button3_Click  doesn't cause error message to appear immediately. I've got impression that if Task is garbage collected, then it throws exception. And if Task is not garbage collected, then exception is generated, but remains in some interesting place. I tried to find some good examples on MSDN, but wasn't very lucky.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Does this still happen when you use `Task.Run` instead?

Comment: If you add the line t.Dispose(); last in the button3_Click handler, do you get the exception?

Comment: If to add Wait and dispose, then yes, error message is generated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could see error throwing from other button handler. It will be evident to you, if you enable **Just My Code** in VS IDE (*Tools-> Options-> Debugging-> General*)

Before I explain why you could see error from `button2` handler and why not from `button3`, it make sense to know how .NET handles Task exceptions.

To start with, both of your `Task` actions are throwing exception those are going `unhandled` by your code. When it comes to `Task`, any `unhandled exceptions` that are thrown by user code is propagated back to the calling thread in the form of `AggregateException`; and this exception raises only when you `Wait` on this `Task` (which case the exception) or call `Result` on it to get the output. In your case, you are not doing either of these and hence your exception go unnoticed. But these exceptions still hang around until tasks are `garbage collected` and will escalate according to .NET exception policy. `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` is something you need to look into if you want to override the exception escalation.

Now coming back to your handlers;

**In case of button2 :** You are asking to perform a deterministic destruction (`using block`) momentarily after starting the task. This means, your task might possibly in `WaitingToRun`, `WaitingForActivation`, `RunningRunning` etc state. According to MSDN, a task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (`RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled`). ***Having said this, exception might not be apparent in all case since it is depend on state of your Task and the moment at which deterministic destruction kicks in.***

**In case of button3:** You are not disposing the `Task` by yourself and leaving it for garbage collector to perform this for you. This is why you can't see any exception. I hope you will be clear on how the exception is handled for you.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx) has detailed explanation on how TASK exceptions are handled in .NET and its covers multiple scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code with VS2015, with the button2, I got the exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A task may only be disposed if it is in a completion state (RanToCompletion, Faulted or Canceled).
```

It is correct as the task is in faulted state.

With the button3, I got nothing. This is correct behavior also: `t.start()` is not a block call, the function `button3_Click` simple just ends.  If you wait for that task, you will get the AggregateException exception.  [Exceptions are propagated when you use one of the static or instance Task.Wait or Task.Wait methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Did you test it not in debugging mode?

Comment: Tested both debug and release

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean testing in 'run without debugging' mode